# Python Triple Nested for Loop not Fully Iterating

Tags: python

Essentially what happens when I run this code is that the "print block[j]" section of my program gets run, but all the test code I have afterwards i.e. print block[k] and print "testing code" is not reached. I've been staring at the program for the last half hour and just can't figure out why the program can reach beyond the 2nd nested loop but not the third.

```
def SwapII(str): 
  new_str = ""
  for letter in str:
    if letter.isupper():
      new_str = new_str + letter.lower()
    else:
      new_str = new_str + letter.upper()

  new_list = new_str.split(' ')


  for i in new_list:
    block = i.split()

    for j in range(len(block)):
        print block[j]
        for k in range(j+1, len(block)):
            print block[k]
            if block[j].isdigit() and block[k].isdigit():
                lala = block[j]
                block[j] = block[k]
                block[k] = lala
                print "testing code"



    i = ''.join(block)


  return ' '.join(new_list)



# keep this function call here  
# to see how to enter arguments in Python scroll down
print SwapII(raw_input())
```

Comment: Have you double-checked `len(block)` is not equal to `1`?

Comment: `i = ''.join(block)` is pointless. You aren't using this value anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? Add a import pdb; pdb.set_trace() before the inner for loop. More info on debugging can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: Try a `print block` before the `for j` loop. And you might be interested in this method: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.swapcase

Comment: What is this code supposed to do exactly, and how is your algorithm intended to reach that goal? You split the string by space, and iterate the words. Then you split those words _again_ by space and try to iterate those, but of course they can not be split any more. What did you expect this code to do?